# 203 Non-Authoritative Information for listing the pat tokens from Azure DevOps using RestAPI with bearer token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to list out the PAT tokens in our Azure DevOps Organization using Bearer Token, however I am getting below error shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Generated bearer token using client credentials flow:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
resource: https://management.azure.com/
```

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=powershell document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I generated one **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
resource: https://management.azure.com/
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to list PAT tokens, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/sridevops14/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview
```

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to generate access token with
> **delegated** flows by changing scope to
> `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`.

In my Azure AD application, I added Delegated `Azure DevOps` API permission and granted **admin consent** to it like below:

[image]

You can make use of below **authorization request** to get `code` value:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran above request in browser, I got `code` value in address bar after signing in successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow by changing scope to `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` with below parameters like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used above access token to list PAT tokens, I got the **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/sridevops14/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I have skipped the username and password for rest api call -https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token as I don't have. Even I have the admin user will have MFA I believe. Anyways, I have followed genereated new token with remaining in the request body, Now I am getting "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: You can check the updated answer where I used **authorization code** flow to generate an access token. Try using `authorization_code` flow instead of *client credentials* flow while generating access token.

Comment: While sign-in I am getting error :  Message: AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

Comment: Go to the **Authentication** tab in your application and add `https://jwt.ms` as Redirect URI like [this](https://i.imgur.com/qc3dGIh.png) and Save.

Comment: You are champion ! It worked :) Thank you so much! Could you share learning pointers how to get this level of knowledge on token handling / AD topics ?

Comment: You can go through official MS documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252769/discussion-between-sridevi-and-uday-kiran).