# PAT Lifecycle Management API returning 203 Non-Authoritative Information

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create an Azure DevOps Personal Access Token via PAT Lifecycle Management API to utilize Work Items API but I am getting 203 Non-Authoritative Information Error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Here’s the curl request:

```
curl --location ‘https://vssps.dev.azure.com/mayankaggarwal9919/\_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1%E2%80%99 –header ‘Content-Type: application/json’ –header ‘Authorization: Basic \\\[Redacted\\\]’ –header ‘Cookie: VstsSession=%7B%22PersistentSessionId%22%3A%229e3cefcb-0bf3-42cb-b3e3-9c76748cb94d%22%2C%22PendingAuthenticationSessionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22CurrentAuthenticationSessionId%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22SignInState%22%3A%7B%7D%7D; X-VSS-UseRequestRouting=True’ –data ’ { “displayName”: “new_token”, “scope”: “app_token”, “validTo”: “2023-12-01T23:46:23.319Z”, “allOrgs”: true } ’
```

I was able to generate a bearer token (that needs to be passed in the PAT API) by registering an app in Azure Active Directory and hitting the below-mentioned curl request in Postman -

```
curl --location ‘https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/token%E2%80%99 –header ‘Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded’ –header ‘Cookie: fpc=Anwji51Th8BHmcdGaAhuKwcrrAAsAQAAAAbCo9wOAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd’ –data-urlencode ‘grant_type=client_credentials’ –data-urlencode ‘client_id={clientid}’ –data-urlencode ‘client_secret={clientsecret}’ –data-urlencode ‘resource=https://management.azure.com/%E2%80%99
```

I tried passing the token to PAT Lifecycle API (the 1st curl request shared above) in different formats like API Key, Basic, and Bearer just to hit and try but got the same error for all of them. Here are the API permissions I have granted to the created app:

[image: App Permissions]

App's API Permissions This is how my application's authentication settings look like -

Application Authentication Settings I also tried generating a bearer token that needs to be passed to PAT API by running this command on Azure Local CLI - az account get-access-token but I am still receiving the same error on passing the generated token in the PAT Lifecycle API.

[image: Authentication Settings]

I am able to access this URL -https://dev.azure.com/mayankaggarwal9919 from the browser and I also made sure that there's no newline symbol in the passed Bearer token. It seems to me that this is happening because of a lack of some permissions which I am unable to figure out.

Any insights will be highly appreciated.

I tried the following things but that didn't solve the problem:

- Providing Azure DevOps Resource Access to the Active Directory App I created.
- Generated Bearer Token (that needs to be passed to PAT API) using Azure CLI instead of Postman.
- Validated all the Permissions related to Azure DevOps on the registered App.
- Generated Bearer token with AAD Application using Authorization Code and Scope as 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
- Checked if there's any newline character present in the Token.`

Answer (score 1):

The error code 203 indicates the bear token is not correct.

The app permission in your screenshot is fine, cause it works from my side.

You can make use of below authorization request to get `code` value:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

You will get the code as below:

[image]

If you encounter the error like `AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.`, please go to the Authentication tab in your application and add https://jwt.ms as Redirect URI like this and Save.
[image]

then you can generate the **access token** using authorization code flow by changing scope to 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default with below parameters like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

With this access token i can generate the PAT in DevOps rest api, please note you can use version `7.0-preview.1` or `7.1-preview.1`, but not `7.0`.

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

[image]

You can check similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75840184/14996050) for your reference.

Comment: @Mayank Aggarwal, may i know if it helps? let me know if you still have queries. If not, would you please help to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that it could help others as well? Thanks.