# Use a service principal to create a Personal Access Token (PAT) for accessing Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm attempting to generate a Personal Access Token (PAT) for Azure DevOps access by utilizing a service principal.

```
# Acquire OAuth Token from Azure AD
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body @{
    App_id = $App_ID
    scope = "1234567..fdsgdyj.798/.default" # Azure DevOps resource ID
    App_secret = $App_Secret
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
}

# Use OAuth Token to Call Azure DevOps API
$apiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/{service}?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer " + $tokenResponse.access_token
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

However, when using the specified API, I encounter an error instructing me to:

> "sign-in at least once in a web browser to enable access to the service."

Comment: may i know if the answer helps? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for the elaborated response. we are working with the access management team to get the required API permissions/access to the SP. I will keep you posted the status.

Comment: sure, let me know if you have any queries. :)

Comment: Thank You @wade zhou - MSFT The given Approach worked. I am now able to generate a PAT token. I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline and implement this programmatically as step1 involves, manually going to redirect url and copy the `code` value.. Do you suggest any workarounds to achieve this? I am currently exploring to have a refreshed tokens to fetch the offline code from the redirect URI.

Comment: I tried to program the step 1 but failed, I'm afraid it's not achievable, as it could ask you to log in if there's no other azure page opened(or cached).

Comment: @wade zhou - MSFT I am generating an offline refresh token and calling the refresh token from a azure pipeline PS task to generate access token. But i am getting below error:
 `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.`

Tried multiple approaches such as splitting the refresh token, added as pipeline variable, variable group, key vault. None of the approaches are working.  But it is working on powershell ISE and getting the response with the same invoke command. 
`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method POST -Body $body`

Comment: it appears a permission error, do you use ARM service connection, and the related service principal(from service connection) has granted the permission as required? Suggest to raise a new ticket with the detail content, error, so that we can check further, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your Response. I will raise another request to follow-up on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same with your code.

The `scope` for the token should be `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` which provides access to Azure DevOps Services REST API.

In short, the `client_credentials` generated can be used to call devops rest api as bear token type, **however it cannot be used to generate Personal access token directly**. You can check below details to generate the PAT.

For example, to list the projects in the DevOps org with the access token, **it works**:
[image]

The service principal is not able to create PAT, message reported: `Service principals are not allowed to perform this action`.
[image]

To use the service principal to generate the personal access token, you need:

1. In my Azure AD application, I added Delegated Azure DevOps API permission and granted admin consent to it like below
   [image]

Add https://jwt.ms as Redirect URI.
[image]

2. make below authorization request to get `code` value:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

You will get the code as below:
[image]

3. then you can generate the `access token` using code above:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

[image]
4. With this access token get you can generate the PAT in DevOps rest api.

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

[image]

You can check similar link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75840184/14996050) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77219746/14996050) for the details.