# Trigger Azure Devops REST API via SP auth

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the below code to trigger Azure Devops REST API via Service principal authentication :

```
$TenantId = "<<>>"
$ClientId = "<<>>"  
$ClientSecret = "<<>>"

$Resource = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com"
$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantid>>/oauth2/token"
$Body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$Resource"
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$bearer_token= $token.access_token

$headers = @{
    Accept = "application/json"
    Authorization = "Bearer $bearer_token"
}

$url='https://dev.azure.com/nandangajananhegde/ITS%20PAAS/_apis/pipelines/17/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
$x=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers;
$x
```

But I am getting the below details in the output :


Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.

<div class="pro

But when I am using Managed Identity authentication via below code , I am getting the necessary output

```
$bearer_token = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"X-IDENTITY-HEADER"="$env:IDENTITY_HEADER"} -Uri "$( $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT )?resource=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798&api-version=2019-08-01").access_token

$headers = @{
    Accept = "application/json"
    Authorization = "Bearer $bearer_token"
}

$url='https://dev.azure.com/nandangajananhegde/ITS%20PAAS/_apis/pipelines/17/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
$x=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers;
$x
```

So what is it I am doing wrong w.r.t Service principal authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same error via your script. To use service pricipal access token, you can check my first sample on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77479149/14996050).

1. The scope for the token should be `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` which provides access to Azure DevOps Services REST API. Add Delegated Azure DevOps API permission and granted admin consent as above link.

[image]

2. You should use `v2.0` for request URI, $Resource is not needed.
3. The service principal(app) should grant permission on the target project. You can [invite the app to the org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#2-add-and-manage-service-principals-in-an-azure-devops-organization), and give contributor role on the target project.

Powershell fixed as below:

```
$TenantId = ""
$ClientId = ""  
$ClientSecret = ""

#$Resource = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com"
#$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token"
$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
#$Body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$Resource"
$Body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$bearer_token= $token.access_token


$headers = @{
    Accept = "application/json"
    Authorization = "Bearer $bearer_token"
}

$url='https://dev.azure.com/nandangajananhegde/ITS%20PAAS/_apis/pipelines/17/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
$x=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers;
$x
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !!! But can you please clarify what does this mean : You should use v2.0 for request URI, $Resource is not needed.    For other Azure offerings, we use the ResourceURI value; so do you mean to say for Azure Devops; you cannot use this aspect

Comment: Yes, you can check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=powershell#personal-access-tokens-pats) which introduce the scope and the [guide link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) inside, it points to OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow. It doesn't have resources and it uses v2.0 in the URI.