# Generate PAT using Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

We are in the process of creating a Personal Access Token (PAT) using a service principal. We were able to generate a refresh token with the scope set as `offline_access` with the code below.

Generate refresh token code:

```
# Azure token endpoint
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Prepare the body of the request
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "authorization_code"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/%2f.default openid profile offline_access"
    code          = $code
    redirect_uri  = $redirectUri
}

# Prepare the headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Make the POST request
$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Later, we were using the refresh token to generate an access token with the same code above but got the below error when running from the Azure ci/cd pipeline.

The same code is working from the local machine - PowerShell ISE.

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx Correlation ID: xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx Timestamp: 2023-11-29 21:32:16Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2023-11-29 21:32:16Z","trace_id":"xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx","correlation_id":"xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"}

We have added these API permissions to the service principal:

[API Permissions of the SP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVhwR.png)

We are implementing the steps from the below Link to generate the access token using the auth code and refresh token:

[Generate Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77478360/use-a-service-principal-to-create-a-personal-access-token-pat-for-accessing-az?noredirect=1#comment136767169_77478360)

Attached the Pipeline Error:

[Pipeline Run Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u5Nd.png)

Here is the PS Code we are using to run the pipeline:
[PowerShell File with the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThMR2.png)

If we are missing anything, please suggest the required permissions to generate an access token.

Comment: @wade zhou - MSFT Could you please look into the question and help suggest the required API permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The same code is working from the local machine - PowerShell ISE.

As it's working on local machine, suppose the permission is already granted. I tried your script, and please check below:

The refresh_token is used to [refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token). You can use below code to get the **new** access token.

```
$tenantID=""
$clientId=""
$clientSecret=""
$redirectUri="https://jwt.ms"
$refresh_token=""


# Azure token endpoint
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Prepare the body of the request
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "refresh_token"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    refresh_token = $refresh_token
    scope         = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
    redirect_uri  = $redirectUri
}

# Prepare the headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Make the POST request
$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -Headers $headers -Body $body
echo $response2.access_token
```

My pipeline result, the accesstoken is created successfully.

[image]

Edit, add the steps to get the refresh_token:

The service principal in your screenshot is fine. I shared the service principal permission again:

[image]

Steps below:

1. Follow the [steps before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77479149/14996050) to get the code on browser on local machine:
   [image]
2. Similar with your code shared, to get the refresh token:

```
$tenantID=""
$clientId=""
$clientSecret=""
$redirectUri="https://jwt.ms"
$code=""   # code from above step


# Azure token endpoint
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Prepare the body of the request
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "authorization_code"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default openid profile offline_access"
    code          = $code
    redirect_uri  = $redirectUri
}

# Prepare the headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Make the POST request
$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -Headers $headers -Body $body
echo $response2.refresh_token
```

[image]

Step3:
**Refresh tokens are long-lived.** Hence, you can use it to get the new access token(script shared at the top). Confirmed the access token can be used to create PAT.

Comment: we are having trouble to generate the refreshed access token. We are getting the same error mentioned in the question. Tried providing multiple API Permissions but still the same. 
@wade zhou - MSFT   Could you please let us know about the permissions assigned to your Service Principal?

Comment: @DevOpsLearner, thanks for your clarification, i have update the reply with the steps to get the refresh_token. The token got from browser is short-lived, but it can get the refresh_token which is long-lived. Once you get the refresh_token on local, you can use it in devops pipeline to create the access token.

Comment: we are following the same but still we are getting a different error each time we modify something in the PowerShell script. I have attached the PowerShell script format and pipeline run error in the question.  we tried multiple approaches by providing the code to generate the refresh token or by providing the refresh token to generate the access token, we also provided the refresh token from variable groups and we tried hard coding the refresh token in the PS file. but none of the approaches have worked. @wade zhou - MSFT Could you please provide the snippet of your yml and PS file?

Comment: @DevOpsLearner, the ps script for refresh_token i have shared above.  I also shared yaml and result in reply above, please check. Use powershell task with `inline` script, remove `param()` for a check.  `Firstly` please try the powershell script on your local machine, make sure the $code value is correct as it looks a little short in your screenshot. and the code is short-lived, it's recommended to generate the refresh_token from local and use refresh_token in pipeline as it's long-lived.