# Azure Devops REST API call from Postman

Tags: azure-devops, oauth-2.0, postman, azure-devops-rest-api, postman-native-app

I am trying to call REST API using OAuth authentication from Azure Devops using Postman.
But, it is giving me error.

PFA the screenshots of the APP, and

[image]

please can someone tell me end to end process to authenticate and get the access token please.

I had tried making the app and using the credentials like -

[image]

But, still not able to fetch.
Please help

This is the Screenshot of the page that open in Azure Devops side to get the authentication - Accept/Deny but after I accept - it comes up with the error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un4b6.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your URL is wrong.  The Postman Authorization helper will be doing the authentication, so the URL you need is the URL for your application.  Not the auth end point.  You haven't even said what error you are getting.

Comment: Hi, can you share the error message you get and the steps you take? By the way, you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/azure-devops-oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75840184/16162444).

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error like : unsupported grant_type, grant_type must be jwt-bearer type, refresh_token, or client_credentials.  I was using grant type as authorization code, but even if I change it to any of the mentioned ones. It gives me error like - invalid resource.

Comment: Hi, you get the error because you didn't write the grant_type in the body with the Content-Type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Please check the detailed steps in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can get the `access_token` following the steps in [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/azure-devops-oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops).

Here are my steps.

1. Go to https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register to register the app.
   We will use the app ID, client secret and the Authorization callback URL in the following steps. My callback URL is https://jwt.ms/ here.

[image]
2. Authorize the app with the app ID and the Authorization callback URL you use in the app.

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize
        ?client_id={app ID}
        &response_type=Assertion
        &state=User1
        &scope=vso.work_full
        &redirect_uri={your Authorization callback URL}
```

After completing the above URL, paste it into your browser and click Enter.

[image]

It will need you to accept the app.

[image]

After we accept it, it redirects the browser to the callback URL, including a short-lived authorization code and the state value provided in the authorization URL. We will use the code in the next step.

[image]

> {callback URL}?code=**eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im.......**&state=User1

[image]
3. Get an access and refresh token by `POST https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token`.  The body `Content-Type`  is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Body details:

```
client_assertion_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
client_assertion:{client secret acquired when the app was registered}
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:{"code" provided via the code query parameter to your callback URL in step 2}
redirect_uri:{callback URL registered with the app}
```

My test result:

[image]
4. With the `access_token` in step 3, we can use it in postman to get the work item details.

My test result:

[image]

5. To refresh token, change the `grant_type` to `refresh_token` and change the `assertion` with the "refresh_token" you get in the step 3.

Body details:

```
client_assertion_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
client_assertion:{client secret acquired when the app was registered}
grant_type:refresh_token
assertion:{"refresh_token" in step 3}
redirect_uri:{callback URL registered with the app}
```

My test result:

[image]

### Note:

You should go to the organization's settings Policy to enable the `Third-party application via OAuth`. This policy is defaulted to off for all new organizations. We need to enable the policy to use the Azure DevOps OAuth apps.

[image]

Comment: Hi Miao, I was trying with another ADO instance - it authorizes ( that is in URL ) but from postman when I am hitting it is giving me error like - "the input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters"

Comment: Hi @MansiGoel, please double check the code you are using contains any additional content.  [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xRD2.png).